# How to use multicol along with multirow?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am tryign to use multirow with multicol.

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c |} 
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{A}               & \multicolumn{2}{c |}{B}                                      \\ \cline{2-3} 
                                                & C                                         &                         D \\  \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{E}                                                         &                         G1  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{E}                                                         &                         G2  \\ \hline    
\end{tabular}
```

Here I want to have only one `E` which should span multirow.

[image]

However, I cant figure out how to use multicol and multirow together.

Comment: The line with `\multirow`asserts implicitly that your table has 4 columns \ you forgot the `\\ at the end of rows.

Comment: you should edit https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611781/how-to-use-multirow-with-multicol not post a new question (but I closed the older one now)

Comment: @Bernard not following - I already have \\ at the end of the rows.

Comment: @Exploring would you like to accept the answer if it met your requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c |}{B} \\ \cline{2-3}
                                                & C & D \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{E}} & G1 \\ \cline{3-3}
     \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & G2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `nicematrix`
package is just right for this with the `Block` command

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|}
        
        \hline
        \Block{2-1}     {A}   &  \Block{1-2}     {B}  &  \\ \cline{2-3}
                              &                   C   & D \\ \hline
        \Block{2-2}     {E}   &                       & G1 \\ \cline{3-3}
                              &                       & G2 \\ 
        \hline

\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: multicol/multirow]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{A}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B}    \\ \cline{2-3} 
                                & C  &  D                   \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{E}} & G1   \\ \cline{3-3} 
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}                   & G2   \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

Old Interfaces: 
\begin{tblr}{|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 \SetCell[r=2]{m} A       & \SetCell[c=2]{c} B &    \\ \cline{2-3} 
                          & C                  & D  \\ \hline
 \SetCell[r=2,c=2]{m,c} E &                    & G1 \\ \cline{3-3} 
                          &                    & G2 \\ \hline
\end{tblr}
\qquad
New Interfaces:
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {|c|c|c|},
  hlines,
  cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{m}, % multorow
  cell{1}{2} = {c=2}{c}, % multicolumn,
  cell{3}{1} = {r=2,c=2}{m,c}, % multirow and multicolumn
}
  A & B &    \\
    & C & D  \\
  E &   & G1 \\
    &   & G2 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]